# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe' in seaborn

Tags: python, machine-learning, seaborn, valueerror

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.lineplot(x="total_bill",y = "size",data = data)
```

when i executed the last line it gives the type error saying

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to
>   dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error (sns.__version__=0.9.0, pd.__version__=0.25.3, matplotlib.__version__=3.1.1).

Comment: I have numpy 32 bit i think it might be the reason
import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo

sysinfo.platform_bits

32

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your array to int32 prior like so:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.int64)
print(type(x[0]))

>> <class 'numpy.int64'>

x = np.array(x, dtype=np.int32)
print(type(x[0]))

>> <class 'numpy.int32'>
```